# How can I prevent cloudfront to cache 307 responses

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using the lambda example from amazon to resize image on the fly https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/resize-images-on-the-fly-with-amazon-s3-aws-lambda-and-amazon-api-gateway/

All works great except when I use cloudfront and I get a "to many redirects" issue.

Here's the thing. The browsers goes to cdn.domain.com/images/200x200/image.jpg
The s3 buckets has a redirections rule when the object doesn't exists and returns to cloudfront a 307 with a new url that points to a API gateway. This 307 is being cached.

Then the lambda associated to this API gateway does the resize process and returns a redirection (301) to cloudfront to the same URL from the begining.

Then, as Cloudfront has cached the response from this URL before, eventhough the object arleady exists it start over by redirecting to the API gateway again , and so on and on and on... resulting a too many redirections error.

How can I prevent cloudfront to cache 307 responses o force S3 redirection rules to tell not to cache.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you solved it? I have same issue.

Comment: I have the same issue with the same exact behaviour.