# AWS S3 images served only via HTTP, but Chrome upgrades to HTTPS

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-chrome, ssl, amazon-s3, https

I am unable to make S3 images hosting to work over HTTPS. I read that *"Amazon S3 website endpoints do not support HTTPS."* - [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteEndpoints.html)

I'm fine with hosting my images over HTTP, however, when I put the following tag in HTML:

```html
<img src="http://MY-BUCKET-NAME.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/images/51612809-741c-40c7-8c29-7b332be709d7.jpg">
```

Chrome requests

```
https://MY-BUCKET-NAME.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/images/c1612a09-741c-40c6-8c29-7b332be709d7.jpg
```

(notice `http` became `https`), which results in `ERR_CONECTION_TIMED_OUT`.

How to make it work?

Comment: Is the website that embeds the Image served via `https`? There was a change to chrome that blocks mixed contents - [chrome blog](https://blog.chromium.org/2019/10/no-more-mixed-messages-about-https.html). If you only use S3 for image hosting etc., you don't need to use static website hosting, you can also just make the images publicly readable and embed their https-url. I'd consider that a better solution in this case.

Comment: @Maurice yes, website is over https. Yes - I know that chrome blockes mixed content. Question still remains - how to make it work? p.s. Thanks for good edit of my question.

Comment: Is `http` something that is for some reason important to you or is upgrading to `https` an option?

Comment: You need to use CloudFront infront of your S3 website to enable https. Have you considered that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments, [Chrome doesn't like mixed content anymore](https://blog.chromium.org/2019/10/no-more-mixed-messages-about-https.html), i.e. it won't let you embed `http` content on a website that's served via `https`.

Now there are multiple options to make this work:

- <strike>Downgrade the main website to `http`</strike> (**don't do this, it's a terrible idea**)
- Make the bucket or at least the objects that you embed publicly readable in S3 and use the native `https` endpoint that S3 offers. It will look something like this:

  ```
  https://<bucketname>.s3.<region>.amazonaws.com/<object-key>.jpg
  ```

  This has essentially the same costs associated with it as your current solution. You might need to do some annoying CORS stuff though.
- Set up a CloudFront distribution in front of your bucket and configure it to serve content from S3. You can use an Origin Access Identity to secure the communication between CloudFront and S3 and even customize TLS-configurations in CloudFront. This will give you caching closer to your users but **comes with extra costs**.

Comment: Thanks @Maurice - I need to use static website because I when S3 image does not exists there is redirection to lambda which creates requested image in requested dimensions (from original image) thus I need to use `s3-website.region`. Even though I made CloudFront with HTTPS it is still not being able to "forward" **freshly created** objects from S3 before these object are distributed to CloudFront cache. Is there any solution for that? In other words, before object is added to S3, and CloudFront can access it via `.s3-website.` there is a few minutes delay.

Comment: Did you use the Error document to do a redirect to an API gateway to trigger a lambda or how did you build that? That sounds like **super weird** implementation :D You could also use a lambda @ edge function in CloudFront that intercepts the response when there is no data in S3 and triggers the lambda.

Comment: My mistake. The real reason is that CloudFront caches 307 response - my exact problem is described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61012822/how-can-i-prevent-cloudfront-to-cache-307-responses

Comment: Okay, does that mean your original question is resolved?

Comment: yes Maurice. Resolved and marked as so. Would appreciate if you have idea about the caching '307' by CloudFront?

Comment: Not really, unfortunately I don't understand your architecture well enough. If you can describe it in a few sentences with maybe a diagram to help us out, feel free to create a new question.